# How can I load the `vsftpd` daemon at system-boot, but have it "start" in a "stopped" state?

Tags: boot, ftp, services, vsftpd

Because I only occasionally need to run an ftp server (*vsftpd*, in my case), I would prefer to just have it *fully active*  only when the need arises.

This suggests two possibilities to me, but I don't know if both (or either) are possible..

*Option 1*: Do not start the daemon as the system boots up,
but instead, start it manually as the need arises... but I don't know the command(s) for this... Maybe it is just "vsftpd" and it will find its own config file(s)... but would this clash with disabling *load-on-boot*?

*Option 2*:. Start the daemon as the system boots up,
but start it in a **stop/waiting** mode... ie. equivalent to `sudo stop vsftpd`, or `sudo initctl stop vsftpd`.

I would prefer Option 1, because I **rarely** need an ftp server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this may depend on which version of Ubuntu you are running. On version 10.10 (and maybe version 10.04) which uses upstart you can edit the `/etc/init/vsftpd.conf` file and comment out the two lines involved with starting vsftpd as so:

```
#start on (filesystem
#        and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
```

The # at the beginning of the lines indicates a comment and will deactivate starting vsftpd on startup.

When you are ready to start vsftpd, you can simply type:

```
sudo start vsftpd
```

at a command prompt to start vsftpd. To stop you would use:

```
sudo stop vsftpd
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks Dennis: Yes! Right on target: "Option 1"...   I am using 10.04 Lucid.. and 'vsftpd' is "upstart"-ed.

Comment: Will `/etc/init/vsftpd.conf` be overwritten when **vsftpd** is upgraded? ... or is this considered by the upgrade process as root's private customization (like my custom $HOME configs)...  I mean: Can I make the mod and expect it **to stay there** unaltered, regardless of upgrades/updates?

Comment: I was concerned about this myself. It should not normally be overwritten since you have modified the file. I did try uninstalling then re-installing vsftpd and my edits to /etc/init/vsftpd.conf were preserved.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the daemon using the following command,

```
sudo service vsftpd stop
```

Add the above command to startup list so that the daemon will be stopped during time.If you want to start the daemon after bootup.Issue the following command in terminal.

```
sudo service vsftpd start
```

Adding the command to Startup list.Goto **System>>Preferences>>Startup Applications**.Click Add and give your command there.
[image]

Comment: Thanks karthick87... An interesting approach for Option 2..  Start it normally, and then quickly **stop** it... but I **think** this would require a manual addition to each user's "startup-list", as it is unknown who logs on first... Things like that tend to get forgotten 6 month down the track when another user is added... or is there an  "all  users" startup list? (there probably is: Linux seems to have most options covered ;)

Comment: Also, doesn't the second thing require the sudo password, so might not work? `rc.local` may be better