# How to make the vsftpd not to start automatically?

Tags: vsftpd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I load the `vsftpd` daemon at system-boot, but have it “start” in a “stopped” state?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16256/how-can-i-load-the-vsftpd-daemon-at-system-boot-but-have-it-start-in-a-sto)

How to make the vsftpd not to start automatically when starting the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Try the update-rc.d tool. This is from it's man page:

> ```
> ...
> Example of disabling a service:
>      update-rc.d -f foobar remove
> ...
> ```